# Creating all types of views dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic

I want to populate all types of widgets (textview, radio btn. drop down, date/time picker ect) according to the server response xml - to create a form. How can I write the code in a more generic way? best architecture for these type of projects pls?

Comment: I had to do the same. I googled, but have got no idea. I just used Switch class and set properties appropriate to that.